# install danish dictionary in emacs on windows

Tags: dictionary, emacs, aspell, flyspell, ispell

I haven't been able to find the help I need on (on dummie level) for installing a new dictionary (danish) in emacs. To be honest I somewhat confused about ispell vs aspell. When typing "M-x ispell-buffer" a spelling control starts using english as default. I can change directory typing "M-x-ispell-change-dictionary" it suggest "dansk" but I get an error saying that the file /.../aspell/dict/danish" can not be opened for reading. I can deduct that the dictionary is not installed - but I cannot seem to finde a guide (step by step) on how to do this.

And then I have a bonus question. I have managed to install flyspell (or is that actually 'installing' as I have just addet the .el file to my emacs load path and loaded in my .emacs file?). This seem to work (wauw), and as I understand it flyspell is using the same dictionaries as ispell/aspell hence solving my probleme above would enable me to use flyspell in danish? 
Any help is appreciated.

/Kira

Comment: `flyspell.el` and `ispell.el` are `elisp` libraries that come with a standard installation of Emacs -- nothing needs to be done to install them.  The `aspell` dictionaries are available publicly on the internet and have `.exe` executable files to install on Windows.  All you need to do is change the dictionary selection like you've noted in your first paragraph -- after you install the dictionary.  Just Google aspell your language windows.  If you do not already have the base installation of aspell, then you need to install that also.  Aspell requires a base installation plus the dictionary.

Comment: Once you install the dictionary and the base aspell (if not already installed), then Google flyspell and ispell emacs -- you will find how to include proper `require` statements and some additional settings that may be helpful.

Comment: Here is a link to the dictionaries:  http://aspell.net/win32/ The base installation is at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu or Debian system you can install the Danish aspell package from the commandline with

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-da
```